# search the directory to get the filename in R

Tags: r

There is a file named `haha` in C:\test, `haha` contains character `look for me`,in linux ,i can search to get the filename.

```
find  /   -name  "look for me"
```

can i search the file with some kind of R command in xp os?
if i don't know the file name which contain character `look for me` is `haha`,how can i do then ?

Comment: Your question is so poorly written. I guess you have 3 questions in there: 1. How to find files named `haha`. 2. How to check if a file contains the string `look for me`. 3. How to find all files that contain the string `look for me`.

Comment: @janos, I think the OP is saying the name of the file is unknown, but it contains the string "look for me."  OP wants to recover the file name.

Comment: Frank ,you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or with plyr:

```
require(plyr) # uses plyr
textFiles<-list.files(pattern=".txt") # only looks at .txt file, you can change or omit
#alply reads each file and returns 
# a list of filenames which pass the grep test
# and indicate the first line identified
mylist<-alply(textFiles,
           1,
           function(f){fline<-grep("LOOK FOR ME",readLines(f))
                        ifelse(fline>0,paste(f,fline,sep=" - line:"),NULL)
           })
Filter(is.character,mylist) # gives you a list of all files containing the term
```

Answer (score 0):

This code wll find a filename with the phrase 'haha' inside of it. And then check if the string "look for me" occurs anywhere within it. Is that what you want?

```
whichfile <- grep(
  x = list.files(),
  pattern = "haha",
  value = TRUE
)

sum(
  grepl(
    x = readLines(whichfile), 
    pattern = 'look for me')
  )
```